# Output filename not configured Error in Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I had installed it globally by running npm install webpack -g and I had included it in my project by running npm install webpack --save-dev.

However, on running the webpack command, I was seeing the following output:
Output filename not configured.

This is the webpack config:

```
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    library: 'require',
    libraryTarget: 'this'
},
```

This is the only clue i could get from the web :: http://anujnair.com/blog/12-output-filename-not-configured-error-from-webpack
But it did not solve the issue

Any Help will be great

Comment: Can you add your webpack [configuration](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html)?

Comment: In my case, I had mistyped my config file `wepack.config.js` instead of `webpack.config.js`

Comment: Like Michelle said: please include your complete webpack.config.js file, plus the file name. The only time I've seen this error was when I failed to create the file with the correct file name.

Comment: Make sure you're exporting your webpack config at the end of the file.

Comment: Hard to say what the problem was, but check to make sure you're in your project's root folder when you run webpack.

Answer (score 17):

I was getting the same error and it turned out to be my webpack config file name.

I had it as "`webpack.config`" instead of "`webpack.config.js`"

The "Output filename not configured" error seems to come up generally when there is a typo somewhere, and I've found the file name to be a sneaky place you forget to check.

Comment: In my case the problem was with `module.export` instead of `exports`

Comment: How funny it is, comment have resolved more problems than the answer did ! hahaha

Comment: Silly mistake: `node_modules/.bin/webpack` instead of `node_modules\.bin\webpack`

Answer (score 10):

Also double-check that the `webpack.config.js` file is in the right spot (in general, the root directory of the project) and the paths listed in the config file are correct.

Comment: that was the problem with me, thanks for suggesting it!

Comment: This was my issue as well!

Answer (score 10):

Common mistakes of this error is typo and most of the times it's writing
`module.export` instead of `module.exports`.
Also check the file name should be with a .js extension. e.g. `webpack.config.js`

Comment: This is the comprehensive solution and module.export (missing 's') was the issue.

Answer (score 6):

You MUST have a file named `webpack.config.js` on project root.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo somewhere in your `webpack.config.js` file. Review your config file. Had similar problem and it was as a result of a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Try exporting your configuration using `module.exports = config` where config is your configuration in a JavaScript object. In your case just do

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    library: 'require',
    libraryTarget: 'this'
  }
}
```

If this does not solve your problems, refer to the issue on https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2403

Answer (score 1):

This error will also occur if you are running the command 'webpack -w' against a directory that does not have a webpack config file.

So if you are opening a new terminal window or tab and haven't changed directory to the root of your project before running the webpack command you will receive the error.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem after following [Webpacks docs for production builds](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/). The way I ran into the issue is, I believe, specific to webpack-merge.

This is what their docs have in webpack.dev.js:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  }
});
```

But this is what I needed to have:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common(), {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  }
});
```

Notice the only change is running `common()` instead of `common`.

Answer (score 0):

If you using `__dirname` make sure it referenced to correct path. Default path is `/` which is local drive root.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and managed to resolve it. The core of the issue was not in fact in the webpack.config.js code, but rather in my entry js file (in my case main.js). Ensure that you have the correct requires and render code. My example code is as follows:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Main = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
         <h1>Hello World, lets see how you React..</h1>
      </div>
    );
  },
});

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Following are the things to check when you get this error.

- Whether your executing **webpack** command in the directory where
  your **webpack.config.js** file resides.
- You may be pointing to the **wrong directory** in your terminal.
- **Typo error** with the file name "webpack.config.js".
- **No Module to export** in your config file.
- Check for **typo error in your config file**

Answer (score 0):

1. create a file @ root directory `webpack.config.js`
2. paste below code in this file

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./app.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  }, 
  watch: true
}
```

3. app.js should also in root directory. write below line in app.js file:

```
document.write('welcome to react v2 app');
```

REF. https://medium.com/@dabit3/beginner-s-guide-to-webpack-b1f1a3638460#.a64eeonhn

Answer (score 0):

just to post my solution. Might help someone.

if you get this error, it always has to do with some typo error. In my case I had forgotten to close the last `}` with a semicolon at the end, like this: `};`

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename:'bundle.js'
    }
};
```

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error when there is a spelling mistake the config details.

```
output: {
    path: "app/dist/assets",
    filname: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "assets"
},
```

mispelled "filename". on correcting the spelling, this issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

also after checking the right file name which should be 'webpack.config.js', a good note is to check where the 'webpack.config.js' file is located. it should be in the same folder as your package.json file is located

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you would be using windows. i ran out into same error and realized i have to do something like this in wiindows 
d:\unpack-webpack> d:\unpack-webpack\node_modules.bin\webpack

instead i was doing 
d:\unpack-webpack\node_modules.bin\webpack

Hope this helps :)
Thanks
Gaurav Khurana

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that webpack.config is in the proper place in the tree. Actually mine was in the proper place but I had to delete the whole file and then replace because the first time I ran web pack in terminal I had missed an underscore for __dirname. Instead of two, I had one. So I ran it with that fixed that a couple times trying this or that and came across this post. So I started over and even though in the same place for some reason it wasn't according to webpack.