# Webpack bundled file not generated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am just new to webpack and react , just going through the docs and created a example to work. Unfortunately i got stuck and not able to proceed . Th problem is the bundled file is not generated. 
 The files i created is

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "rohith",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.export = {
    entry : './main.js',
    output : {
        path : './',
        filename : 'index.js'
    },
    devServer : {
        inline : true,
        port : 3333
    },
    module : {
        loaders : [
            {
                test : /\.js$/,
                exclude : /node_modules/,
                loader : 'babel',
                query : {
                    presets : ['es2015','react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <div>Hello</div>
    }
}

export default App
```

**main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('app'));
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>Setup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "app"></div>
    <script src ="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting that bundle is valid, but no index.js is generated.
can't run in localhost 3333

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In webpack.config.js, use `module.exports` instead of `module.export`. See [Output filename not configured Error in Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157313/output-filename-not-configured-error-in-webpack)
Also be noticed that your `package.json` lacks some dependencies. Here is the updated `package.json` that works:

```
{
"name": "rohith",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^15.4.1",
  "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
  "webpack": "^1.13.3",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel": "^6.5.2",
  "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0"
}
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I think the problem is that you are not giving the absolute output path.

Try this:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry : './main.js',
    output : {
        path : path.join(__dirname, './'),
        filename : 'index.js'
    },
    devServer : {
        inline : true,
        port : 3333
    },
    module : {
        loaders : [
            {
                test : /\.js$/,
                exclude : /node_modules/,
                loader : 'babel',
                query : {
                    presets : ['es2015','react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 5):

Replace your scripts object with the below:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -p && webpack-dev-server"
  },
```

Then, run `$ npm start`

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was with package.json under that "scripts"

Here is the fix:

Inside your package.json file, under script add the following:

> "scripts": {
>      "start": "webpack-dev-server", 
>      "build": "webpack -p"
>    }

First I ran the build then start.

> yarn build

if you first build then your bundle.js file will be created and after that you can use this command:

> yarn start

Answer (score 1):

In case of no output file (bundle.js) and a successful build

```
Hash: 77a20ba03ab962a1f5be
Version: webpack 4.41.0
Time: 1039ms
Built at: 10/04/2019 5:24:48 PM
Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
main.js  1.09 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = main.js
[./react_rest/frontend/src/index.js] 35 bytes {main} [built]
+ 12 hidden modules
```

**webpack** :

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './react_rest/frontend/src/index.js',
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        }]
    },

    output: {
        filename: 'main.js'
    }
};
```

Try to use `var path = require('path');` and allocating output **directory**

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './react_rest/frontend/src/index.js',
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        }]
    },

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname,'./react_rest/frontend/static/frontend/'),
        filename: 'main.js'
    }
};
```